# The equivalent of SQLServer function SCOPE_IDENTITY() in mySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql-server

What is the equivalent of SQLServer function [SCOPE_IDENTITY()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx) in mySQL?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

[This](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html) is what you are looking for:

```
LAST_INSERT_ID()
```

In response to the OP's comment, I created the following bench test:

```
CREATE TABLE Foo
(
    FooId INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE Bar
(
    BarId INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
);

INSERT INTO Bar () VALUES ();
INSERT INTO Bar () VALUES ();
INSERT INTO Bar () VALUES ();
INSERT INTO Bar () VALUES ();
INSERT INTO Bar () VALUES ();

CREATE TRIGGER FooTrigger AFTER INSERT ON Foo
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Bar () VALUES ();
    END;

INSERT INTO Foo () VALUES (); SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

This returns:

```
+------------------+
| LAST_INSERT_ID() |
+------------------+
|                1 |
+------------------+
```

So it uses the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` of the original table and not the table `INSERT`ed into inside the trigger.

**Edit:** I realized after all this time that the result of the `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` shown in my answer was wrong, although the conclusion at the end was correct.  I've updated the result to be the correct value.

Comment: Thanks Sean. How does it behave when the table I am inserting the data into has a trigger that inserts data in another table which has an autoincrement field too? Would it return the ID of the original table or the one affected by the trigger?

Comment: What will happen if we had multiple requests coming in to insert a row in the table? Would it return the correct value that the admin requested?

Answer (score 3):

open **MySql** command type `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();` then **ENTER**

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE Identity_Temp
(
    Id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    Name varchar(200)
);

INSERT INTO Identity_Temp (Name) VALUES ('A');
INSERT INTO Identity_Temp (Name) VALUES ('A');

SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();

DROP TABLE Identity_Temp;
```

You get last inserted identity value from using LAST_INSERT_ID() and you can used any table insert as well