# Better rewriting of a 3 mySQL query sequence?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

When a successful register happens there is an Insert into members table. It has an id filed auto increment.

```
//Create INSERT query
$qry = "INSERT INTO members(email, passwd) VALUES('$email', '$password')";
$result = mysql_query($qry);
```

Because I need to save some of the input in another table named companies, I find the total records ( that means the last ID)

```
//find lastid from members
$lastid = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select count(id) as lastid from members"));
$lastid = $lastid[lastid];
```

and save it into the table companies.

```
//Insert lastid to Companies
$insertit = mysql_query("INSERT INTO companies( id, name) VALUES('$lastid', '$cname' )");
```

This is working successfully but is there a better way of doing this ? I have removed some of the fields to give a better more to the point example.

Comment: I can't provide a full answer, but you may want to look into using `LAST_INSERT_ID()`. More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/560783/the-equivalent-of-sqlserver-function-scope-identity-in-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `members.id` is an `AUTO_INCREMENT` field you can cut a bit out using `mysql_insert_id()`:

```
//Create INSERT query
$qry = "INSERT INTO members(email, passwd) VALUES('$email', '$password')";
$result = mysql_query($qry);

//find lastid from members
$lastid = mysql_insert_id();

//Insert lastid to Companies
$insertit = mysql_query("INSERT INTO companies( id, name) VALUES('$lastid', '$cname' )");
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [mysql_insert_id](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) to get the last inserted id.

`"select count(id) as lastid from members"` does not mean the last id for many cases.

Comment: +1 - very important especially if there's concurrency.

Answer (score 0):

Counting the total records in the table does not guarantee that it is the last id. A better option is get the max value of the id column:

```
SELECT MAX(id) AS lastid FROM member
```

But the best option I think is to use the [mysql_insert_id](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) function:

```
$qry = "INSERT INTO members(email, passwd) VALUES('$email', '$password')";
$result = mysql_query($qry);
$lastid = mysql_insert_id();
```

Comment: Getting `MAX(id)` is never a better option. They both are terrible and should never be used at all.