# Twisted - Using a Deferred for another sql query

Tags: python, mysql, asynchronous, twisted, deferred

I've got a twisted based network application. Now I would like to implement a new database design but I''m getting stuck with the Deferred object.

I write sessions into my database by using this two functions:

```
def createSession(self, peerIP, peerPort, hostIP, hostPort):
    SessionUUID = uuid.uuid1().hex
    yield self.writeSession(SessionUUID, peerIP, hostIP)

    sid = self.db.runQuery("SELECT id FROM sessions WHERE sid = %s",
                           (SessionUUID,))

    yield sid

@defer.inlineCallbacks
def writeSession(self, SessionUUID, peerIP, hostIP):
    sensorname = self.getSensor() or hostIP

    r = yield self.db.runQuery("SELECT id FROM sensors WHERE ip = %s",
                               (sensorname,))

    if r:
        id = r[0][0]
    else:
        yield self.db.runQuery("INSERT INTO sensors (ip) VALUES (%s)",
                               (sensorname,))
        r = yield self.db.runQuery("""SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()""")
        id = int(r[0][0])

    self.simpleQuery(
        """
        INSERT INTO sessions (sid, starttime, sensor, ip)
        VALUES (%s, FROM_UNIXTIME(%s), %s, %s)
        """,
        (SessionUUID, self.nowUnix(), id, peerIP))
```

In short words:
createSession creates an UUID for the session and calls writeSession to write this into my db. After this is written I try to select the ID of the last insert by using the UUID in the where statement and return the result.

Now my problem. To update the session information I call this function:

```
def handleConnectionLost(self, sid, args):
self.simpleQuery("UPDATE sessions SET endtime = now() WHERE sid = %s",
                 (sid))
```

As you can see I try to use the sid from createSession which is an Deferred object and not an integer. If I got this right and I add a Callback to `handleConnectionLost` it will run the query at this time so that I can use the value here. But this is not my only function where I need the sid. So it would be an overhead when I do every time a callback when I need the sid.

1. Is there a way that I can give my sid as an integer to my functions? So that I'm just running the query one time? How does it have to look like?
2. When I'm using a Deferred query with a `now()` statement. Will it use `now()` when I added this query to my Callbacks or will it use `now()` when the query is fired?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can immediately get the ID after inserting a new row for later use, similar question was answered here: [The equivalent of SQLServer function SCOPE_IDENTITY() in mySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560783/the-equivalent-of-sqlserver-function-scope-identity-in-mysql)
2. it will use now() when the query is fired

Comment: 1. Cause I've got other tables where I would like to use the sid as an foreign key where the UUID whould be a little bit nasty. This was the easiest part as an good example what I'm doing or what it should doing.
2. answered, thx :)

Comment: That's true but I've still got the Problem how to return the result of this query. ;)