# How to insert many related records in one sql file

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to insert many records in  3 tables, `businesses`, `business_categories` (`business_id`), `business_details`(`business_id`),  I want to insert many data.

as you can see,   the data in business_categories and business_details will need to use the business's id, and when inserting data, I still don't know the business id.

in the past, I was writing a ruby script to do that things, but it's pretty slow.  and now I want to write a script to generate sql file directly, it can be the fast way.

I would write this.

```
insert into businesses(name, ..) values ("blabla", ...)
insert into business_categories(business_id, ..) values(? ..)
insert into business_details(business_id, ..) values(? ..)
```

Is it possible to set the right value to the `?` ?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could save the last inserted id to a variable and set that value in the following inserts.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17112962/1165441

This answer has some info that is really good.

Comment: I think  LAST_INSERT_ID() should work in the second line,but on the 3rd line, last_insert_id changed, it's become the last business_categories's id,  what should i do to insert business_details?

Comment: Assign it to a variable before doing the second insert.

Comment: `set @lastid := last_insert_id()`

Comment: Oh, Thank you, Thank you. It's so great. I didn't know there is variable in mysql .  you are so great!