# How to handle a secondary INSERT related to a primary INSERT

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jsp

I have 2 tables: user and photos (in a mysql db).

Here you can see the relation between the 2 tables

```
    User                          Photos
-----------------   -------------------------------
|  id  |  user  |   |   id_user   |   photo_url   |
-----------------   -------------------------------
   ||                      /\   
   ||______________________||
   |________________________|
```

When I save a new user into the table "user", if the insert is done successfully, I have to take the value of the "id" field of the user just saved, and save it inside the "id_user" field of the table "photos", in order to make a relation between a user and its photos.

Making the first insert (table "user"), then getting, with a SELECT, the "id" of the last record and then again saving the user's photos it's not the right way to do it.
How should i do it?

Comment: it can help  , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17112852/get-the-new-record-primary-key-id-from-mysql-insert-query

Comment: you can make use of last_insert_id()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the auto-incremented ID for the previous insert, you'll want to use [mysql_insert_id()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html).

Answer (score 0):

use this toobtain user id:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id

30chars