# How to insert data when there are multiple foreign keys in table

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

How to insert data whenever multiple foreign keys in table
means a database which contains patient, Doctor, and staff
Patient: an appointment must be with a patient
Doctor: every appointment must have a doctor

My question how to insert data within appointment and another related table like patient, doctor at same time?

Give me an example please?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `doctor` (
  `doctor_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `doc_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `contactNum` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `qulification` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `joiningDate` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `u_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`doctor_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;
```

Doctor
doctor_id: 1
doctor_name : Ali
Qulification : mbbs

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `patient` (
  `patient_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `sex` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  `diagnosis` text NOT NULL,
  `DOB` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `Contact_No` varchar(111) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`patient_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

patient
```

patient_id:1
Name: Ahmed Zubair
sex: Male
diagnosis : test
DOB : 20/6/2000
address : islamabad

```
CREATE TABLE appointment 
(
  appointment_id int NOT NULL,
  doctor_id int NOT NULL,
  patient_id int NOT NULL,
  Date int NOT NULL,
  time int,

  PRIMARY KEY (appointment_id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_ap_pa_id FOREIGN KEY (patient_id) REFERENCES patient(patient_id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_ap_do_id FOREIGN KEY (doctor_id) REFERENCES doctor (doctor_id)
);
```

Comment: you can't. you have insert data into the patient AND doctor tables first, THEN you can create an appointment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the first comment, you need to first insert records into the `patient` and `doctor` tables, and then you can insert your appointment record. If these need to happen in a single operation (e.g., all succeed or all fail) then wrap the insert statements in a transaction.

I don't have a MySQL instance available to completely vet the code required, so I can't post it, but follow this process:

1. INSERT your `doctor` record
2. Save the primary key generated using `LAST_INSERT_ID()` into a local variable
3. INSERT your `patient` record
4. Save this primary key into a new variable using the same process as step 2
5. *Now* you can INSERT your appointment record using these two variables in the statement to ensure you satisfy the foreign keys

Again...if this is an atomic operation, then wrap these statements in a transaction that includes any validation or error checking your situation requires.

More info about `LAST_INSERT_ID()` here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/17112962/571237

Comment: Local variable? How explain me please

Comment: Take a look at the documentation - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html. I think you should be able to write something like `SET @doctorPK = LAST_INSERT_ID()` and then use that variable in your final insert statement.

Comment: Tell me easiest way please.. I'm very new in mysql

Comment: I've tried to do that with my answer and follow up comments.

Comment: Trying...if give one example it's much better to understand things

Answer (score 0):

In order to achive this you should use transaction, more detail about this you can read

- [First](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html)
- [Second](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-transaction.aspx)
- [Third](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mysql-transaction.php)

Thanks