# How do I get an ID when it is being inserted into a database

Tags: php, mysql

How do I explain this....

Basically say if I create a post, I click submit, the following database insert would happen

```
$sql="INSERT INTO comments (userid, topicid, category, topicname, comment, date, name, avatar)
 VALUES
 ('$row[id]','$content[id]','blogs','$content[topic]','$_POST[comment]','$today','$row[name]', '$row[cavatar]')";
```

now say at the same time of that post I want another INSERT query running, how do I get the AUTO created ID number from the first query into the second query?

second query would be

```
$notifyme="INSERT INTO notifyme (userid, catid, category, date,time)
 VALUES
 ('$row[id]', ,'comments','$date','$time')";
```

they both run the same time but I need the AUTO created id number off QUERY 1 to insert under CATID for QUERY 2

```
$sql="INSERT INTO comments (userid, topicid, category, topicname, comment, date, name, avatar)
 VALUES
 ('$row[id]','$content[id]','blogs','$content[topic]','$_POST[comment]','$today','$row[name]','$row[cavatar]')";

$notifyme="INSERT INTO notifyme (userid, catid, category, date,time)
 VALUES
 ('$row[id]', ,'comments','$date','$time')";
```

is how it looks when ran, both will be running the same time

Comment: `last_insert_id()`, and you are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: See a duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17112852/get-the-new-record-primary-key-id-from-mysql-insert-query

Comment: what Marc said, or another method I use is to do a query select, run a while loop, assign a variable to an `id` row, and add `+1` to it. I use it often. But Marc's suggestion is better.

Comment: [You're someone's "mentor"...](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30605835/) there @MarcB

Comment: if @MarcB could post this as an answer I will give the answer credits to him :)

Comment: @LonelyRanger He can't; he closed the question.

Comment: darn well it was very handy as I had no clue how to phrase my question or if it made any sense lol

Comment: @LonelyRanger which MySQL API are you using to connect with? `mysql_`, or `mysqli_` or PDO?

Comment: then http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php is the one to use. I've outlined a few comments in an answer given below. They just need to adjust their answer in regards to that function. @LonelyRanger should you want to just basically accept it; the choice is yours, but again... they need to adjust their answer with the correct function for the matching MySQL API.

Comment: @LonelyRanger I've decided to modify and improve the answer given below, should you want to accept it and close the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you said in comments that you are using the `mysqli_` API to connect with, use `mysqli_insert_id()` for retrieving a record id after each query ran.

Reference:

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

---

Sidenote:

Your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/). Use [**prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they're much safer*.

Comment: oh for crying outloud. Running on Marc's comment. tsk tsk

Comment: I was probably faster add? :D

Comment: nah, he beat you by a whole minute lol plus he added a bonus answer ;-) but I like mine too.

Comment: great, so we are getting somewhere.

Comment: either way, OP gets their dessert. *yummy*

Comment: there is "one" tiny detail though... we don't know which MySQL API the OP is using to connect with. Be it `mysqli_` or `mysql_` or PDO. All they've shown us was the raw query. It could even be  [`mysqli_insert_id()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php) or [`PDO::lastInsertId()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php)

Comment: we don't, but probably the author knows this?!

Comment: well yeah.... but you're assuming they're using `mysql_`. and `mysql_insert_id()` doesn't work with `mysqli_` or PDO ;-)

Comment: greate modification, anywhoe you are  native english person!