# How to access mysql assigned primary key in other column

Tags: mysql

I have this mysql query:

```
insert into table_products values (NULL, '$product_name', '$product_description', '$image_path', '$brand_id', 1)
```

Since product_id is an auto_increment primary key, passing NULL will assign it the next available integer.

It is the same integer I want to assign to an image path with some pre and post string string.

For example, if the product_id is assigned as 900, I want to assign image_path to 'somestring/' + 900 + '.png' i.e something/900.png

How to get this 900 for the image path column while inserting in to table.

Comment: What sort of code are you using to execute this statement? Is it just a sql script or is it in Java or some other programming language?

Comment: Looks a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17112852/get-the-new-record-primary-key-id-from-mysql-insert-query

Comment: You can use SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would probably need to do a separate query and update that column with the id that was just inserted, eg:

do your insert:

```
insert into table_products values (NULL, '$product_name', '$product_description', NULL, '$brand_id', 1)
```

Then grab the id using mysqli_insert_id or PDO::lastInsertId and set the path string eg:

```
$id = mysqli_insert_id($connection);
$path = 'somestring/' . $id .'.png';
```

Then update the previous row with the path:

```
UPDATE table_products SET path =  '$path' WHERE product_id = $id;
```

Comment: Thanks for very quick response. Even i thought of this solution. But here for every insert two queries to be executed. Can't we avoid that?

Comment: As far as I know you can't access the insert id until after the insert has been completed, forcing the second query, but it is a good question.