# How to return the last id of inserted query?

Tags: sql, vb.net

I'm trying to insert a record in the local database and after it I want to get the id 'cause I need to re-use this `id` for insert another record in a different table. Now this is my code:

```
 ...
 Using dbCon As MySqlConnection = establishConnection()

        Try

            dbCon.Open() 

            Dim MysqlCommand = New MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO users (first_name, last_name, email, 
                                phone_number, address, city, notes, id_roles, data) 
                                OUTPUT INSERTED.ID
                                VALUES(@first_namep, @last_namep, @emailp, @phone_numberp, 
                                @addressp, @cityp, @notesp, @id_rolesp, @data)", dbCon)

            MysqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@first_namep", name)
            MysqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@last_namep", last_name)
            MysqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emailp", email)
            MysqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone_numberp", phone_number)
            MysqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@addressp", address)
            MysqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cityp", city)
            MysqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@notesp", notes)
            MysqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_rolesp", customer_id)
            MysqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data", 0)

            MysqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()  

            Dim id As Integer = MysqlCommand.ExecuteScalar   

            MysqlCommand.Parameters.Clear()


            MysqlCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO user_settings (id, username, password, salt)
                                       VALUES(@idp, @usernamep, @passwordp, @saltp)"

            MysqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idp", id)
            MysqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usernamep", username)
            MysqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@passwordp", password_hash)
            MysqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@saltp", password_salt)

            MysqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

        Catch myerror As MySqlException

            MessageBox.Show(myerror.Message)

        Finally

            dbCon.Dispose()

        End Try
    End Using

End Sub
```

I open the connection with `dbCon.Open()` and after it I perform a parametized query passing all controls values. Now the id on the table is `auto_increment` so I've write in the query:

```
OUTPUT INSERTED.ID
```

but when this line is going to executed: `MysqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()`

I get this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OUTPUT INSERTED.ID VALUES('Jason', 'Ruos', '' at line 3

What am I doing wrong? I hope also that my `.Clear()` is a good practice for re-use the MySqlCommand.

Comment: I think the OUTPUT keyword isn't supported by MYSQL (I could be wrong).  Your query looks like a Microsoft SQL statement.  See [Get the new record primary key ID from mysql insert query?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17112852/719186)

Comment: But SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID(); must require to execute in another query, isn't possible return the inserted id in the same query?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, just use:

```
Dim id As Integer = MysqlCommand.LastInsertedId
```

Answer (score 0):

you are almost there. Instead of using `MysqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()` , use `MysqlCommand.ExecuteScalar()`

also I notice you add all your parameters etc , call `MysqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()` then you try to use the executescalar() again which is saying run this stored procedure again. get rid of the first `MysqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()` and just use the one you are assigning to an ID