# How to return the autoincremented BIGINT key of the row inserted in MySQL through JDBC?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have a table, say `Users` with an auto-incremented primary key of type BIGINT.

In Java, I'm looking to

- insert a row to `Users`
- return the key of that row inserted.

I tried the following without much expectations since the key field of `Users` is `Long` and `executeBatch()` is returning an integer array.

```
String query2 = "INSERT INTO Users (name, status) VALUES (?, ?); "
                    + "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();";
    // ... code deleted for clarity
int [] tmp = pStat.executeBatch();
```

The array returned out of this code is empty.

How to do this in MySQL?

I've seen [Get the new record primary key ID from mysql insert query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17112852/get-the-new-record-primary-key-id-from-mysql-insert-query) and some other relevant discussions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass `Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS` as one of the arguments while creating `preparedstatement`, have a look at javadoc [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#prepareStatement(java.lang.String,%20int)):

> autoGeneratedKeys - a flag indicating whether auto-generated keys
>   should be returned; one of Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS or
>   Statement.NO_GENERATED_KEYS

Code would look like this:

```
PreparedStatement pStat = connection.prepareStatement(SQL_INSERT,
                                      Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
```

Once the statement gets executed, you can get the keys via `getGeneratedKeys()` method (javadoc [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getGeneratedKeys())):

```
ResultSet rsKeys = statement.getGeneratedKeys();
//Iterate the resultset using next
```