# Need help in converting PostgreSQL into mysql in Node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, postgresql, surveyjs

Below function I copy it from [surveyjs-nodejs repository](https://github.com/surveyjs/surveyjs-nodejs/blob/master/dbadapter.js) and looking to achieve this similar into mysql.

```
    function getObjectFromStorage(tableName, callback) {
    db.any("SELECT * FROM " + tableName).then(function(result) {
      var objects = {};
      (result || []).forEach(function(item) {
        objects[item.id] = item;
      });
      callback(objects);
    });
   }

 getObjectFromStorage("surveys", function(objects) {
  if (Object.keys(objects).length > 0) {
    callback(objects);
  } else {
    callback(surveys);
  }
});
```

how this .any works?

```
db
  .one("INSERT INTO surveys (name, json) VALUES($1, $2) RETURNING *", [
    name,
    "{}"
  ])
  .then(callback);
```

and how this **RETURNING *** use in mysql?

Thanks

Comment: You can check the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17112852/get-the-new-record-primary-key-id-from-mysql-insert-query

Comment: Thank you @TSV for your reply, I am able to convert returning* into mysql  :)