# MySQL - insert rows in one table and then update another with the auto increment ID

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables called `applications` and `filters`. The structure of the tables are as follows:

```
mysql> DESCRIBE applications;
+-----------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | tinyint(3) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name      | varchar(255)        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| filter_id | int(3)              | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> DESCRIBE filters;
+----------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type                 | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | smallint(5) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name     | varchar(100)         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| label    | varchar(255)         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| link     | varchar(255)         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| anchor   | varchar(100)         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| group_id | tinyint(3) unsigned  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| comment  | varchar(255)         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
7 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

What I want to do is select all the records in `applications` and make a corresponding record in `filters` (so that `filters.name` is the same as `applications.name`). When the record is inserted in `filters` I want to get the primary key (`filters.id`) of the newly inserted record - which is an auto increment field - and update `applications.filter_id` with it. *I should clarify that `applications.filter_id` is a field I've created for this purpose and contains no data at the moment.*

I am a PHP developer and have written a script which can do this, but want to know if it's possible with a pure MySQL solution. In pseudo-code the way my script works is as follows:

1. Select all the records in `applications`
2. Do a `foreach` loop on (1)
3. Insert a record in `filters` (`filters.name` == `applications.name`)
4. Store the inserted ID (`filters.id`) to a variable and then update  `applications.filter_id` with the variable's data.

I'm unaware of how to do the looping (2) and storing the auto increment ID (4) in MySQL.

I have read about [Get the new record primary key ID from mysql insert query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17112852/get-the-new-record-primary-key-id-from-mysql-insert-query) so am aware of `LAST_INSERT_ID()` but not sure how to reference this in some kind of "loop" which goes through each of the `applications` records.

Please can someone advise if this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible to do this with only one request to mysql.

But, i think this is a good use case for mysql triggers.

I think you should write it like this :

```
CREATE TRIGGER after_insert_create_application_filter AFTER INSERT
ON applications FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO filters (name) VALUES (NEW.name);
    UPDATE applications SET filter_id = LAST_INSERT_ID() WHERE id = NEW.id;
END
```

This trigger is not tested but you should understand the way to write it.

If you don't know mysql triggers, you can read [this part of the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html).

Comment: And you can also do some things when you delete or update an app. What do you think of this answer ?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer to your question, more a comment on your database design.

First of all, if the `name` field needs to contain the same information, they should be the same type and size (`varchar(255)`)

Overall though, I think the schema you're using for your tables is wrong. Your description says that each record in `applications` can only hold one `filter_id`. If that is the case, there's no point in using two separate tables.

If there is a chance that there will be a many-to-one relationship, link the records via the relevant primary key. If multiple records in `application` can relate to a single filter, store `filters.id` in the `applications` table. If there are multiple filters for a single application, store `applications.id` in the `filters` table.

If there is a many-to-many relationship, create another table to store it:

```
CREATE TABLE `application_filters_mappings` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `application_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `filters_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

Comment: Thanks for this but it's not an answer to the question. The database I'm working with is in a legacy application so changing table structures isn't appropriate. There will only be 1 `filter_id` record per row in the `applications` table (since it exactly corresponds to a record in `filters`). I'm only interested in knowing if it's possible to write an SQL statement to do the looping/updating as opposed to making structural changes to tables. Thanks though.