# How can I get the id of a record inserted into mysql database in visual basic?

Tags: mysql, .net, vb.net

I am trying to get the Id of the inserted record, because I need to insert data with the generated Id. Help me please.

I´m using visual basic 2008 express edition

This is my code:

```
        Dim id_header As Integer
        Dim queryHeadReceta As String

        'TRANSACTION IN CASE INSERTS FAIL
        transaction = connection.BeginTransaction()

        cmd.Connection = connection
        cmd.Transaction = transaction

        'GENERATE HEADER ID
        queryHeadReceta = "INSERT INTO tb_receta_enc(cant_despensa, id_usuario) VALUES(@cant_despensa, @id_usuario)"

        Try
            cmd.CommandText = queryHeadReceta.ToString
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@cant_despensa", txt_cant_bolsa.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("id_usuario", 1)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()


           'here I want to get the id to use in new records


            transaction.Commit()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
            transaction.Rollback()
        End Try
```

Comment: Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17112962/9365244

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the new record primary key ID from MySQL insert query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17112852/get-the-new-record-primary-key-id-from-mysql-insert-query)

Comment: See also [C# Data Connections Best Practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17552829/c-sharp-data-connections-best-practice)

Comment: If `cmd` is a `MySqlCommand` object, you can just read the `cmd.LastInsertedId` property after `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`.