# How to get currently inserted row id in laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Here I am using laravel 5.5. My code is

```
$result = DB::insert('INSERT INTO .......');
```

Here it returns true. But how can I get inserted id? In my table id is the primary key. Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not use Eloquent ORM?

Comment: I need to executive raw sql and get id.... because sql comes from my db

Comment: Maybe executing this as a single statement: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17112962/5192105

Comment: be careful with using raw my friend, I've seen a video where you can get SQL injection with raw. try to use eloquent or query builder better. just personal opinion :).

you can find the video by search "How your Laravel application can get hacked, and how to prevent that from happening by Antti Rössi" on Youtube,

Comment: Why do you must use a `RAW QUERY` instead of [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent) ? If you are doing basic operations **`Eloquent`** is a must, no excuse...

Answer (score 2):

you can use `insertGetId()`.

> If the table has an auto-incrementing id, use the insertGetId method to insert a record and then retrieve the ID:

```
$id = DB::table('users')->insertGetId(
    ['email' => 'john@example.com', 'votes' => 0]
);
```

doc can be found [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#inserts).

Comment: is it possible by using like **DB::insert('INSERT INTO .......');**

Comment: no..insert will return either true or false.

Comment: But I need to executive raw sql and get id.... how can I ? because sql comes from may db

Comment: you mean you must use `INSERT INTO` ??

Comment: then there's no built in method to get the inserted id. you can make a query to get the id yourself. want me to give you an example??

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using DB method you can simply use Laravel eloquent:

```
$result = <YOUR_MODEL_NAME>::create(<YOUR_DATA>)->id();
```

it return the last inserted record id.

And make sure if you use this method you need to add $fillable in your MODEL like:

```
class <YOUR_MODEL> extends Model
{   
    protected $fillable = [ 'column_name_1', 'column_name_2', .., 'column_name_n' ];
}
```

Comment: But I need to executive raw sql and get id.... how can I ? because sql comes from my db

Comment: But why you use the raw SQL instead of eloquent? Laravel eloquent is easy to use. Just try at once. :)
If you don't want to use eloquent then try this : $id = DB::getPdo()->lastInsertId();

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = MODEL_NAME::create(data);
return $result->id;
```

try this may be it's working

Comment: But I need to executive raw sql and get id.... how can I ? because sql comes from my db

Comment: then you can use this  $id = DB::table('table_name')->insertGetId(
    ['field_name' => 'Filed_data']
); return $id;

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you order your rows and get last id?

```sql
select <primary key> from <table> order by desc limit 1;
```