# MySQL auto assign foreign key ID

Tags: mysql, sql, python-3.x, mariadb, innodb

I have a main table called `results`. E.g.

```
CREATE TABLE results (
    r_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    r_date DATE NOT NULL,
    system_id INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (system_id) REFERENCES systems(s_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

The systems table as:

```
 CREATE TABLE systems (
    s_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    system_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);
```

I'm writing a program in Python with MySQL connector. Is there a way to add data to the `systems` table and then auto assign the generated `s_id` to the `results` table?

I know I could `INSERT` into `systems`, then do another call to that table to see what the ID is for the `s_name`, to add to the `results` table but I thought there might be quirk in SQL that I'm not aware of to make life easier with less calls to the DB?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the new record primary key ID from MySQL insert query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17112852/get-the-new-record-primary-key-id-from-mysql-insert-query)

Comment: It sounds like you want a trigger or a separate insert.

Answer (score 1):

You could do what you describe in a trigger like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER t AFTER INSERT ON systems
FOR EACH ROW
  INSERT INTO results SET r_date = NOW(), system_id = NEW.s_id;
```

This is possible only because the columns of your `results` table are easy to fill in from the data the trigger has access to. The auto-increment fills itself in, and no additional columns need to be filled in. If you had more columns in the `results` table, this would be harder.

You should read more about triggers:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-trigger.html
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/triggers.html