# How can ı save automaticcly generated primary key as a foreign key in another table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables named **portfolio** and **portfolioplants**. A one portfolio could be have multiple plants. When user create new portfolio with plants from API ı want to hold the **portfolioID(PrimaryKey)** and **portfolio name** in portfolio table, and hold the plants of portfolio's in **portfolioplants** table with **portfolioID**(ForeignKey) and **plants** of portfolio. What I'd like to do is, ı want to save **portfolioID** value (which is auto-incremented in portfolios table as a PK) in the **portfolioID(FK) column** of **portfolioplants** table **automaticcly**. So here is my sql querys:

```
app.post('/api/savePortfolio',(req,res)=>{
   const portfolioName = req.body.name
   const plants = req.body.plants
   const sqlInsertportfolio = "INSERT INTO portfolios (name) VALUES (?)"
   db.query(sqlInsertportfolio,[portfolioName],(err,result)=>{
       if(err) console.log(err)
       console.log(result)
       res.status(200)
   });

   const sqlInsertPortfoliofPlants = "INSERT INTO portfolioplants (plantName) VALUES (?)"
   plants.forEach(plant=>{
       db.query(sqlInsertPortfoliofPlants,[plant.name],(err,result)=>{
           if (err) console.log(err)
           console.log(result)
           res.status(200)
       })
   })
})
```

here is the portfolios table:

[image: portfolioID(PK) and portfolioName]

and here is the portfolioplants table:

[image]

I'd like the portfolioID column to be filled with the auto generated portfolioID value of its portfolio.
THX in advance for your suggestions and have a healty day :))

Answer (score 0):

I have my solution like this way. Hope it helps to people who suffers with same issue with me :)

```
app.post('/api/savePortfolio',async (req,res)=>{
const portfolioName = req.body.name
const plants = req.body.plants

const sqlInsertportfolio = "INSERT INTO portfolios (name) VALUES (?)"
db.query(sqlInsertportfolio,[portfolioName],(err,result)=>{
    if(err) console.log(err)
    res.status(200)

    db.query('SELECT MAX(ID) as "portfolioID" from portfolios',(err,result)=>{
        if(err) console.log(err)
        var portfolioID = JSON.stringify(result[0].portfolioID)

        const sqlInsertPortfoliofPlants = "INSERT INTO portfolioplants (portfolioID,plantName) VALUES (?,?)"
        plants.forEach(plant=>{
            db.query(sqlInsertPortfoliofPlants,[portfolioID,plant.name],(err,result)=>{
                if (err) console.log(err)
                console.log(result)
                res.status(200)
            })
        })
    })
});})
```

Comment: This only works assuming there have been no other inserts.   It is possible someone else could insert another row in between your inserts and you will pick up the wrong ID.
Have a read of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17112852/get-the-new-record-primary-key-id-from-mysql-insert-query

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. I'll check this out. thx a lot :))