# How can i get ID when insert into a table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, insert-into

I insert values in a table but I want to get column's id while I am inserting ;
These are my code ;

```
$addInsurance = mysql_query("INSERT INTO insurance (coo_Country,pod_Country,startDate,finishDate,insGNumber,insKNumber,customer_customer_ID) VALUES ('$cikiscity','$variscity','$baslangicTarih','$bitisTarih','$yetiskin','$cocuk','$customer_id') SET '$ID'=insurance_ID");
if (!$addInsurance) {
    echo'Could not run query' . mysql_error($connection);
}
```

I want to get insuranse_ID in  insurance Table how can I do it ?

Comment: Are you possibly looking for an `UPDATE` statement instead?

Comment: @mario, I guess OP is looking for `LAST_INSERT_ID()`

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/560783/the-equivalent-of-sqlserver-function-scope-identity-in-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this on your else statement:

```
else {
  echo mysql_insert_id();
}
```

Though I do not recommend it because MySQL extension is deprecated in newer versions of PHP. Generally to issue queries to MySQL programmers use the [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) or the [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) extension of PHP. Try doing it using MySQLi if you can. It's equivalent is the mysqli_insert_id() function.