# INSERT and SELECT in a single query string MySql C#

Tags: c#, mysql

I need to insert a row and use that "last id" immediately so I need to execute a query like this

```
INSERT INTO table_name (col1, col2,...) VALUES ('val1', 'val2'...);
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

I know that to INSERT I must call `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`
and to SELECT I call `cmd.ExecuteReader()`

But how to do both in a single query?

Comment: You can use something like scope identity....https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560783/the-equivalent-of-sqlserver-function-scope-identity-in-mysql

Comment: Best way would propably to use a stored procedure.

Comment: This case can only be solved by putting all commands into stored procedure then use `ExecuteReader` and get `SELECT` output result from it.

Comment: Thank you, I will try stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following after insert query:

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM tablename;
```

or

```
SELECT fields FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
```