# How to insert data through multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I am learning SQL and I created this database to offer a cinema reservation service.

[image: cinema booking service]

My problem is that I can't make a reservation because my reservation table doesn't have a foreign key to table room. I also can't create a relation from reservation to table room because that would violate the normalization rules.

An reservation without a reserved seat doesn't make sense.
Can you give me an advice how I can solve that?

I am using MySQL.

Comment: "I can't make a reservation because my reservation table doesn't have a foreign key to table room". So create the foreign key (ie the room).  It doesn't make sense to create  a reservation if the room doesn't exists.

Comment: Wouldn't that violate the normalization rules?

Comment: It's the same as the manual process would have to be.  Enter a new room into the table.  Make a reservation using that room.  You can't use the room before it exists in the correct table.

Comment: Can you post a sample of what you're trying to insert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do your inserts in sequence.  Create the lowest level entry first then ascend the sequence.

If I need a room to make a reservation then I create the room before I create the reservation. If you need to pull the identity value of the row that you just created so that you can pass it along the process then you can use LAST_INSERT_ID(). 
[The equivalent of SQLServer function SCOPE_IDENTITY() in mySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560783/the-equivalent-of-sqlserver-function-scope-identity-in-mysql)

As an example of passing a key along:

```
Declare PassedKey Integer; 

INSERT INTO TableRoom values (...) 
SET PassedKey = LAST_INSERT_ID()

INSERT INTO TableReservation values (PassedKey, ...)
```

Comment: I assume that I have your table names incorrect but I cannot view your attachment for some reason.

Comment: The `SCOPE_IDENTITY` and the link you mentioned here are related to MSSQL but in the question is mentioned that MySQL is used.

Comment: modified to the MYsql version of the function.